# No result from window.PKVideoThumbnail.createThumbnail function call in Phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-desktop-app

I am working Phone gap project in which I am displaying video thumbnail to users after they upload video files. But I see neither the success result nor the error message.

I have installed plugin by following command as specified in doc and it got installed also.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-photokandy-video-thumbnail --save
```

I am using latest version of plugin. My question is do we need any configuration in config.xml? or is it issue with my code?

```
var sourceVideoPath = "file:///"+device_local_path; 
var targetThumbnailPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "demo.PNG";        
window.PKVideoThumbnail.createThumbnail (              
sourceVideoPath,targetThumbnailPath, thumbnailsuccess, thumbnailfailure );
```

I tried to write both external memory and internal memory, But no use.

And does it work with Phonegap Desktop app or Do we need to test on actual devices using executable files? In this scenario I tried both. But did not work out.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to preview your app using the PhoneGap Desktop, when the PhoneGap Desktop serves to either the PhoneGap Developer App or the Browser platform it only supports the [core PhoneGap Plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/plugin-apis/).

There is a [workaround to get the PhoneGap Developer App](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer#adding-custom-plugins) to support previewing of non-core plugins.

Comment: Okay Herm.Thanks for the response. I am testing on actual device using Phone gap build apk. Do you know why video thumbnail plugin is not working?

Comment: I don't have any experience with the video thumbnail plugin. My only suggestion would be to put in some `console.log` statements to see if the correct path to the video are being returned.